# multiple targets in multiple ifs, depending on one another VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, target

I have a data table, in which, set of rows need to be hidden based on criteria set in different set of cells. 
I wrote something which basically is "cave man coding" and of course it does not work :)

I have created if's and tried to put ifs within ifs, but literally nothing is happening with this code.

I only wrote it 2 sets of rows, but it is around 30 different sets (not yet written)

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range(Cells(7, 8), Cells(7, 8))
Set Target1 = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 2))
    If Target.Value = "No"
        Rows("8:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Half" Then
            Rows("22:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Full" Then
            Rows("8:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If

Set Target = Range(Cells(30, 8), Cells(30, 8))
Set Target1 = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 2))
    If Target.Value = "No"
        Rows("31:56").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Half" Then
            Rows("47:56").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Full" Then
            Rows("31:56").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So, in a short summary i have two variables in cell B3 (Half and Full)

and in Row H in specified cells  (e.g. H7, H30 and so on) Yes/No options. 
rows 7, 30 (any row, having Yes/no option) are headers of topics
from 8 to 29 details of this topic are included.

if H7 (H30 ...) is No - entire details should be hidden (rows 8-29; 31-56 and so on) - Valua in B3 does not matter.
If H7 (H30...) is Yes, then value in B3 matters:
If H7 (H30...) is Yes and B3 is half - rows 22-29 hidden (47-56 and so on) rows 8-21 are unhidden in this case 
If H7 (H30...) is Yes and B3 is full - rows 8-29 are unhidden.

Hope i explained it well.

Please help me to improve my code, to be able to do set goal.

Comment: Please put option explicit as the first line of your code.  Then resolve the compile errors that adding that statement will show.  You should also qualify the use of Range and Cell with the workbook and worksheet name.  e.g. Workbook_name.Worksheet_name.Range

Comment: I googled what needs to be done after putting the line, i am confused honestly. Could you please clarify it more?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **then** from your if statements and also **elseif**

Here is the code that should work for you:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Target1 = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 2))

' ------------

Set Target = Range(Cells(7, 8), Cells(7, 8))

If Target.Value = "No" Then
    Rows("8:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Half" Then
    Rows("22:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Full" Then
    Rows("8:29").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

' ------------

Set Target = Range(Cells(30, 8), Cells(30, 8))

If Target.Value = "No" Then
    Rows("31:56").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Half" Then
    Rows("47:56").EntireRow.Hidden = True
  ElseIf Target.Value = "Yes" And Target1.Value = "Full" Then
    Rows("31:56").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

End Sub
```

As the **Target1** range reference does not change, you do not need to repeat setting it throughout your code.